# Десериализация JSON массива объектов с динамическим ключом

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

Имеется JSON

{"ltc_btc":{"high":0.02114521,"low":0.01962913,"avg":0.02038717,"vol":207.13475109,"vol_cur":10229.28905866,"last":0.0201777,"buy":0.02007017,"sell":0.02017982,"updated":1519244404},"nmc_btc":{"high":0.00027499,"low":0.00025951,"avg":0.00026725,"vol":0.09797934,"vol_cur":374.49630245,"last":0.00025951,"buy":0.00025587,"sell":0.00027106,"updated":1519243695}}

Получаю ответ и дессериализую с помощью Retrofit

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://yobit.net/api/3/") 
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        YobitApi yobitApi = retrofit.create(YobitApi.class);
        Call<GroupPair> call = yobitApi.getTicker("liza_rur-btc_rur");
       GroupPair pair = call.execute().body();

  public class GroupPair {
        @Expose
        public Map<String, Pair> pairs;
    }
```

Добавил класс GroupPair, в котором описал объект как пару ключ(например ltc_btc) и непосредственно объект Pair. Но после десериализации получаю свойство pairs равным null. Возможно необходимо реализовать конвертер, для того чтоб GSON знал как дессериализовать данный массив объектов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, десериализацией занимается не retrofit, а [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).
Во-вторых, так не получится. В этой ситуации может быть несколько вариантов.

Первый. Если известны ключи, в `GroupPair` создаете свойства `ltc_btc`, `nmc_btc` и т.д. Тут, я подозреваю, ключи неизвестны и будут постоянно меняться, но метод самый простой, да. Например.

```
class GroupPair {
    @SerializedName("ltc_btc") Map<String, Object> ltc;
    @SerializedName("nmc_btc") Map<String, Object> nmc;
    ...
}
```

Второй. Если ключи неизвестны и вам бы добраться до каких-то значений, и без pojo. Сразу возвращать `Map`.

```
Call<Map<String, Map<String, Object>> call = ...
```

Третий. Опять без pojo, возвращать JsonElement и работать с ним как обычным json объектом с проверками на существование ключей, приведением к JsonObject и т.д. Неплохой вариант когда структура неизвестна, часто меняется или когда глубина дерева объектов слишком большая, чтобы на каждый уровень по pojo классу создавать.

```
Call<JsonElement> call = ...
```

Четвертый. Похоже на предыдущий, работаем с только с тем, что нас интересует. Написать свой десериализатор. Понятно, что имея возможность добраться до json элемента в момент парсинга дает неограниченную свободу что куда парсить и в каком виде получать результат.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://yobit.net/api/3/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(
        new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(GroupPair.class,
            new TypeAdapter<GroupPair>() {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, GroupPair value) throws IOException {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
                @Override
                public GroupPair read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
                    GroupPair result = new GroupPair();
                    result.pairs = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, new
                        TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
                    return result;
                }
            }).create()))
     .build();
 Call<GroupPair> call = ...
```

ЗЫ С классом `Pair` также ничего не получится, gson пишет в свойства по их наименованиям или именам сериализации (аннотация `@SerializedName`). Если вы имеете в виду `android.util.Pair` (или `android.support.v4.util.Pair`), то у него есть свойства `first` и `second`, которых нет в вашем json'е и вы опять получите пустоту в данных.
ЗЗЫ `Map<String, Object>` во всех случаях лучше заменить на какой-то класс (`Rates`, например), в котором создать все необходимые для работы свойства. В четвертом варианте тогда будет `result.pairs = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Rates.class);`